# Karate Ui automation

Tags: automation, automated-tests, karate

Hi i am facing an issue with to read the table values by using script all when I am trying to execute getting this error “no step def method found for scriptAll” can you please any one can suggest how to resolve that issue?

I written like this
When def list = scriptAll('tr td', '_.textContent')

Comment: The issue got resolved but now try to get only 10 values out of 20. Can any one can suggest how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are on an old version of Karate. Upgrade.

If still facing issues, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: The issue got resolved but now try to get only 10 values out of 20. Can any one can suggest how to get it?